# Why does this function produce (0,0,0,0,0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_new_list = []
for num in my_list:
    my_new_list.append(num-my_list[num-1])
print(my_new_list)
```

I don't understand what [num-1] is doing in terms of indexing to return (0,0,0,0,)
Can someone please explain this because I can't wrap my head around why this would be the result.

Comment: Just run through the code with a debugger? Inspect the variables? Did you use the dev console?

Comment: I agree with @trincot. It is a very obvious problem and you wouldn't have to ask if you would have used a dev console

Comment: Add a print statement in each loop so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

When the loop is processing the first element of the list, `num` is `1`, so `num-1` is `0`. It then uses that as the index in the list, and `my_list[0]` is `1`. Subtracting `1-1` returns `0`, and that gets pushed into `my_new_list`.

The same thing happens for every element, because the value of each element is its index + 1, so you get `0` every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

my_list[num-1] is taking the first element i.e, 1 from the list.

```
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_new_list = []
for num in my_list:
    my_new_list.append(num-my_list[num-1])
    print(num,my_list[num-1])
print(my_new_list)
```

You can run this code, the output would be:
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

As for num in my_list picks each element from the list.

Answer (score 0):

When this loop executed, first time gives:

`my_new_list.append(1-my_list[1-1])` is equal to `my_new_list.append(1-my_list[0])` is equal to `my_new_list.append(1-1)`

second time:

`my_new_list.append(2-my_list[2-1])` is equal to `my_new_list.append(2-my_list[1])` is equal to `my_new_list.append(2-2)`

third time:

`my_new_list.append(3-my_list[3-1])` is equal to `my_new_list.append(3-my_list[2])` is equal to `my_new_list.append(3-3)`

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The result is Understandable, inside your loop, **my_num[num-1]** is subtracted from **my_list** whose contents are 1,2,3,4,5.

when num is **my_list[0]==1**, the first iteration, the value of **my_list[1-1] = my_list[0]**. So it is effectively the same as subtraction the individual elements of the list by itself thus giving [0,0,0,0,0].

Hope that this Helped you understand the behavior :).